# Converting a doc to a pdf in a mvc c# environment

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, iis

Hi I've got a c# MVC application running under a particular user (app.pool user).
I need to convert a doc or docx file to a pdf.

I thought a good option would be to use libreoffice to fire a process that would start this.

To make life easier for myself (and if libreoffice shouldn't work) I used a batch file.

```
echo on

SET var1=%2

IF "%var1:~-1%"=="\" SET var1=%var1:~0,-1%

cd %var1%

echo %1

echo %var1%

start /wait "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\soffice" -headless -convert-to pdf %1 -outdir %var1%
```

My code for starting this is as follows.

```
var ba = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\apps\xxxxxxxxx\Services\convert.bat";
                fullPath = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\apps\xxxxxxxxx\Files\Temp\636295920370843147.doc";
                var tempPath = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\apps\xxxxxxxxx\Files\Temp";

                string command = ba;

                //Process.Start(command, fullPath + " " + tempPath);

                var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command + " "+ fullPath+ " "+ tempPath);
                processInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

                process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
                    Trace.WriteLine("output>>" + e.Data);
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();

                process.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
                    Trace.WriteLine("error>>" + e.Data);
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                process.WaitForExit();

                Trace.WriteLine("ExitCode: {0}", process.ExitCode.ToString());
                process.Close();
```

This does seem to work manually but when I run the code I can see the whole thing just stalls around the conversion. Looking at the threads and it seems to load the gdiplus.dll which I think is a graphics module which doesn't seem right.
[image: Threads]

[image: Process]

The process though when I copy and paste that into my 'run' box in windows works fine and the pdf is made.

I've checked that the app.pool user has access to both libreoffice and also the folder with the files.
I've ran this as the app.pool user, in the c# it just stalls on the `process.WaitForExit();`
line. Until I kill the process.

Any ideas?

I've also tried **many** different ways of executing the soffice conversion. just straight from the c# - libreoffice 4,5.

I've seen some people use libreoffice as a service, is this an option? If so how?
Richard

EDIT
Ah, just changed the app Pool user to myself and now it works, so there is a permissions thing with the standard app pool user. How to find out what....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the user into the administrators group on the computer and restarted the machine, then it worked.

It might not be the best solution but after 2 days of trying to get this to work I'm not going to argue.

Richard