# How to convert doc to pdf using LibreOffice and C#

Tags: c#, libreoffice, file-conversion

The string that I'm using to convert the documents is as below. I'm not sure if it's a problem with the parameters passed to soffice.

> soffice --convert-to pdf --outdir C:\test\NPP\LOTestOutputs\ C:\test\NPP\MBI_CONVERSION_PRESETS.docx

Also tried:

> soffice --convert-to pdf C:\test\NPP\MBI_CONVERSION_PRESETS.docx --outdir C:\test\NPP\LOTestOutputs\

And this is passed to a code in c# which starts a process and executes the arguments passed to it. **The problem is that the process waits endlessly at proc.WaitForExit()**. I was able to execute a simpler command [soffice --convert-to pdf MBI_CONVERSION_PRESETS.docx] from the cmd prompt

```
..some more code above related to process init
proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

I referred to a similar problem on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898938/converting-a-doc-to-a-pdf-in-a-mvc-c-sharp-environment) And I checked that my user account has administrator rights. And I am not sure why I cannot convert the document using libreoffice.

The libreoffice version : 5.4

Hoping to get some tips on stackoverflow. Please let me know if you need any info regarding my tests.

**EDIT 2: the error read from the stream**

```
{Error: Please verify input parameters... (SfxBaseModel::impl_store <C:\test\NPP\LOTestOutputs" -env:OOO_CWD=2C:\\Users\\dev\\source\\repos\\Converstion\\TestClass\\bin\\Debug/MBI_CONVERSION_PRESETS.pdf> failed: 0x81a)}
```

Comment: Could it be that nobody reads the process error or stdout? After reading the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.beginerrorreadline?view=netframework-4.7.2) I understand you'll probably need event handlers which read the output away. A simple way to check that your setup is correct is to write a trivial program which just emits an error and an output string and call it instead of LibreOffice.

Comment: I also noticed that in the example mentioned the (error) output is set to redirected, and `proc.Start()` is called only as the last step. Conceivably you cannot change the process setup after it has started.

Comment: Last not least it would help to boil down your program to a small, self-contained example (because "..some more code above related to process init" may contain the problem). Last not least because you may already find the error in the process.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: I have the code where I can read the error and the output stream. I have updated the error info in the question.

Comment: One thing that caught my eye was "Convers**t**ion" ....

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, my stay in france is messing up with my english.I will change the spelling. Thank you :)

Comment: I was thinking that the directory "Converstion" does not exist (because it is named "Conversion"), which is keeping Libreoffice from producing the PDF "verify input parameters"). It should still cleanly exit though, so it's ony half the problem, if at all. (Ah, I only now see your own answer. Good find :-).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output path was the main culprit here. The directory shouldn't contain the trailing backslash. I posted the same question on a different website and got the answer. The dev team might come up with a fix for the trailing backslash.

Link to the answer shared [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/167263/how-to-convert-doc-to-pdf-using-lo-commandline/) for more reference.

Thanks everyone!